# Powerdot paper orientation (or page width?) suddenly changed

Tags: winedt, powerdot

My system:

- Windows 10
- MikTeX 22.3 (I think that's what it tells me when it starts. First there is a nerd joke about pdfLaTeX 3.14159...)
- WinEdt 10.2
- Workflow: .tex -> .dvi -> .ps ->.pdf

I am about to finalize the process of porting my TeX-system to a new laptop. The only difference (I think) to the previous set up is the MikTeX upgrade from last summer.

The hopefully last hurdle I just ran into is the following. Suddenly my powerdot slides come out on a paper in portrait orientation as opposed to the expected landscape. The contents is still in landscape as it should, see the image below.

[image]

So either the orientation or the page width is out of whack (the script may also be larger, but I'm not 100 per cent sure). But shouldn't the powerdot package make the necessary modifications as a matter of course. What the hell is wrong in my configuration? The exact same source file worked fine last year with an older MikTeX but otherwise the same system (barring the possibility of an incomplete WinEdt customization).

**Possibilities:**

1. Something wrong in my WinEdt configuration. I have zero trust in my understanding of the zillion options there. Yet, I don't recall running into this problem ever before.
2. The unusual thing is that in the last step of my workflow ps2pdf gives me the following message:

> %%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dNOSAFER

This is something I don't recall seeing earlier either, so it is probably related. Unfortunately I cannot make head or tails of that. If I gave Google the buzzwords *ps2pdf* and *-dNOSAFER* it asks whether I really want to search for *-dSAFER* instead, and only gives hits to generic ps2pdf manuals, which does not help me one bit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to run dvips with the option landscaperotate: `dvips -landscaperotate yourfilename`

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer! That fixes the problem. In WinEdt I had to insert that into the appropriate box in Options -> Execution modes. I also checked that this won't affect the output when the usual portrait output is expected (with a different source file). I don't recall having to use that option in the older versions, but now it works anyway (too late an hour for me to fire up the older laptop and check the options there). You are welcome to post that as an answer also. Your call, of course :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call `dvips` with the option `-landscaperotate`

```
dvips -landscaperotate file
```

Newer version of `dvips` no longer rotate the media box if landscape
is used. (See e.g.
https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2021-July/047291.html and the
discussion in the `dvips` manual)

That means to get a landscape page one must setup the page size
correctly with landscape values but powerdot still relies on the now
deprecated rotation from `dvips`.

Comment: Ok. So a feature as opposed to a bug :-)

Comment: well as I triggered the change I naturally think that it is a feature. But you should report it to powerdot, they should probably adapt to the change.

Comment: Ok. In WinEdt `-landscaperotate` seems to be a permanent option, i.e. affecting every call to dvips. I am slightly worried about the option doing some damage to some other file that would be better off without. The first test did not reveal anything like that, so likely there is a safeguard. I'm happy with this.

Answer (score 1):

A friend had the same issue when he was using `paper=screen`. I could reproduce in my computer and I found that changing to `paper=a4paper` seems to work.

Regarding:

> %%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dNOSAFER

I did just what it was suggested:

```
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER my-file.ps
```

And the warning was gone but, as far as I can see, there's no visible difference in the final PDF. Perhaps it's just a red herring.

Comment: paper=a4paper works for me. :-)