# powerdot: slides no longer rendering (problem with dvi files?)

Tags: dvi, rendering, powerdot

I have many powerdot slides that have rendered successfully in the past. Today, I re-rendered one of my old files using the same command as before but now, the slides are all cut-off on the right-hand side. I tried opening just the .dvi file and the previewer (YAP) will not open it at all (though the .ps and .pdf files will open).

I re-installed the latest version of MikTex to see if that would help, but alas, no. I also tried just a simple slide (one slide with just text) to see if my figures or perhaps, other packages were the culprit, but that didn't help either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SE. You don't show any code, any error and any result, so unless you can provide a good crystal ball it's going to be difficult to help… Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655669/1090

Comment: Thank you David Carlisle - the post that you suggested had the solution!
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655669/1090